# How to generate unique QR codes with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

I want to generate a unique QR code with Laravel. I found [this link](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-57-qr-code-generator-exampleexample.html), but I think it doesn't make a unique one every time.

Comment: Library that you linked accepts the text that gets encoded into the barcode. You are supposed to provide that text. Why would you need "unique every time" from a library? It's not how libraries are used.

Comment: I need a unique qr code for every user when signing in from mobile. Can u help ?

Comment: If you need unique QR code, then make one.

Comment: the QR codes that are being generated, are being generated from a string, if you provide the library with unique strings, the QR codes will also be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use qr-code with keygen for unique QR.

- https://github.com/endroid/qr-code
- https://github.com/gladchinda/keygen-php